# Problems with input

Tags: ruby

I am playing around with codeacademy Labs and put in the following:

```
sent = gets.chomp
```

And when I input a string containing an apostrophe, `"I'm done"`, a window pops up telling the program is taking too long. Why is that the case? Is it just an issue with the interpreter?

Comment: What is `gets`? A string?

Comment: Just issue with codecademy site, I assume. Try with local ruby.

Comment: @zeantsoi: it's Kernel#gets.

Comment: Try escaping the apostrophe by putting `\\` in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

This was likely an issue with Codecademy's servers. There is no code-specific reason for a simple `gets` command to cause a timeout.